# Python Selenium get data with xpath from td inside tr

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I'm using Selenium in my Python project, I want to get data inside a Table with this code:

```
xpath = "//div[@id='tab_highscore']//table[contains(@class, 'highscore')]//tr"
users = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)

for u in users:
    xpath = "//td[@class='name']"
    userTd = u.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[0]
    user = userTd.get_attribute('innerText')

    xpath = "//td[@class='score']"
    scoreTd = u.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[0]
    score = scoreTd.get_attribute('innerText')

    usersArr.append({"name":user, "ally":ally, "score":score})
```

The problem that in user and score I'm always getting the first tr values, any idea what is the problem?

Comment: You are getting the first values because you are selecting it by index `[0]`, you might need to loop through that list.

Comment: @Stack But in the loop, I'm searching for the `td` inside the `tr`, `u` represent the `tr`

Comment: Add a `.` in the xpaths of `userId` and `scoreId` so it looks like this `".//td[@class='name']"` and ".//td[@class='score']" respectively

Comment: Its difficult to tell without html code of table. add the html code of table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify *context node* (a dot in the beginning of XPath expression) that points to specific `u` on each iteration:

```
for u in users:
    xpath = ".//td[@class='name']"
    userTd = u.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    ...
```

P.S. Use `find_element_by_xpath(xpath)` instead of `find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[0]` and `.text` instead of `.get_attribute('innerText')`